# Building an game with Electron and a website, but how can i open the electron app with a button on the site? PHP Based

Tags: php, electron

Hay!

Im trying to make a game, all webbased. But im using an electron application for the game client. But is there a way for opening the electron app by clicking a button?

Usercase :

1 User login on the website
2 User press Go to game client
3 Browser gives you a pop up Do you want to open $Name client?
4 it opens

I know that you can do that with the exec command, but not everyone installs the game in the same directory. So can you give it a unique ID ?

Comment: `exec` would open something on the webserver where PHP is running, not on the user's machine. Imagine if you could execute aribtrary commands on a user's machine from a web application...what fun the hackers would have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a protocol handler.

Protocol handlers are highly customized to each use-case so take a look at this guide first: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app

First thing to note is this'll only work if the Electron app has already been installed on the user's computer.

This is what I think you need:

> If the Electron app **is not running**, clicking the "Go to game client" button in the browser will open the Electron app.

You'll need to setup the protocol client with `setAsDefaultProtocolClient` like it describes in the guide.

---

> If the Electron app **is running**, clicking the "Go to game client" button in the browser will show the existing Electron app, not open a new one.

You'll need to use `requestSingleInstanceLock` and the `second-instance` like it describes in the guide.

---

Protocol handlers are definitely the way to go. I'd recommend having a go at it and if you need any more help ask a new question here, on StackOverflow.

<sup>PS: protocol handlers only work on Linux if the Electron app is installed which makes it hard to develop them for Linux.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look on it, and try it out :)